# Install Mono Project Offline on Centos 7.0

Tags: linux, centos, mono

I want to install Mono on CentOS 7. My problem is that I can't connect my machine to the internet.

What Packages do I need to download for complete installation?

Answer (score -2):

1. Open your Terminal window
2. Create the mostlinux repo file on file `/etc/yum.repos.d` through the command:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mostlylinux.repo
   ```
3. Activate Vi's insert mode (<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) and paste the following lines on the body of the `mostlylinux.repo` file:

   ```
   [mostlylinux]
   name=MostlyLinux
   baseurl=http://mostlylinux.com/6/$basearch/os
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=http://mostlylinux.com/6/RPM-GPG-KEY-mostlylinux
   ```
4. Save your file by pressing (<kbd>ESC</kbd> + `:wq` + Enter)
5. To install Mono use the command:

   ```
   sudo yum install -y mono-devel
   ```
6. To install Monodevelop use the command:

   ```
   sudo yum install -y monodevelop
   ```

That's it. That's all you need to get the latest versions of Mono and Monodevelop running on your CentOS 6.2 distribution.

Comment: Where i have to placed my repo folder ?

Comment: inside /etc folder.

Comment: From where can i download the Repos ?

Comment: 1. Why should he trust your 3rd party repo? 2. He clearly states he wants to use monodevelop for CentOS 7, not 6. 3. The OP also stated he has no internet connection.

Comment: That's in every aspect a bad answer. Nearly should be flagged as "Not an answer".

Comment: @JodkaLemon yes, it is a bad answer since it's not really answering the specific question with respect to centOS 7. However, it is an answer, of sorts.

Comment: @terdon ...and not with respect to offline setup. Question: CentOS 7 offline Answer: CentOS 6 online.